# Programaticaly retreive version history changes of an Sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, version-history

In Sharepoint CSOM (c#) how to retreive the item version history for a particular version. For example for an item there are 8 major version. In that i need to retreive programatically 2nd version changes history

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read ListItem Version Data with CSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233030/how-to-read-listitem-version-data-with-csom)

Comment: the link which you have provided it will retreive Modifiedby, modified date but my requirement is to retreive the changes have made from previous version and this version. Please suggest

Comment: Ouh. Alright - I would suggest using a script written by "Jerry_MSFT" and modify it by getting specific version (instead of looping through all versions) and creating a new variable where to store field value of the desired version.

Comment: can you please share the link for the script? that would be great helpful

Comment: The script itself is located in other thread (link in the first comment as "possible duplicate"). I suggest to modify the script that is provided by our member "Jerry_MSFT" (see the answer)

Comment: As in the image i need to get only changed filed name and changed values for that version. in sharePoint which field those changed fields and values are stored for each version? Please suggest